# How to compress multiple js file and save to single file using YUI Compressor

Tags: java, yui-compressor

I follw this links [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632725/how-can-i-combine-and-compress-multiple-script-and-css-files-for-production-use) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957748/yui-compressor-compress-multiple-input-files-into-one-output-file) to compress multiple js file and store a single file. But its not working  for me

I tried:

```
  java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar --charset utf-8  async.js  OrbitControls.js > compress.js
```

But, its **only compress** first js file(**async.js**) and save to **compress.js** But Not Compress **OrbitControls.js**

I need to Compress multiple js file and save to single file , Suggest me How to do this.

Answer (score 1):

first combine the file from command windows.use type command for it in windows(same as cat command of unix)

```
type file1 file2 > combinedFile
```

After combining the file combinedFile run it through the YUI compressor.
How to write the proper command have a look in to this

> [Link](https://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)